# displaying current date in a text box - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having great difficulty getting the current date to be inputted into a text box within a form i am creating as a default value. at the moment i have the following code, which i believe creates the current date, followed by the text box code which i am unsure on how to modify in order for the date to be displayed inside.

```
function getDate(){
 var todaydate = new Date();
 var day = todaydate.getDate();
 var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
 var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
 var datestring = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
 document.getElementById("frmDate").value = datestring();
} 
<input type="text" name="frmDateReg" required id="frmDate"  value="getDate()">
```

if anyone could suggest how to create todays date and input it into the textbox as default it would be greatly appreciated. (Please excuse any format issues as i am new to stack overflow) Thanks

Comment: Setting `value="getDate()"` is not going to execute your function. You need to add a script that calls getDate() from js.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea.  It's just out of order:

```
<input type="text" name="frmDateReg" required id="frmDate" value="">

function getDate(){
   var todaydate = new Date();
   var day = todaydate.getDate();
   var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
   var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
   var datestring = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
   document.getElementById("frmDate").value = datestring;
  } 
getDate();
```

Your code is correct, except that adding the function call in the value doesn't do anything.  You need something else to trigger the function.  The way I have it there, it will execute automatically when the page loads.

Aslo, datestring is not a function.  It's just a variable.  So you can leave off the ()

Comment: unfortunately i have amended the code however it still does not display the date in said text box, it is just blank, is there a reason for this box still being empty? thankyou for your reply regardless

Comment: Check your console.  I suspect it's because of the order of things loading on the page.  If the INPUT element hasn't rendered yet, there is no place to put the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Jquery code, this will work

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var dateNewFormat, onlyDate, today = new Date();

        dateNewFormat = today.getFullYear() + '-';
        if (today.getMonth().length == 2) {

            dateNewFormat += (today.getMonth() + 1);
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1);
        }

        onlyDate = today.getDate();
        if (onlyDate.toString().length == 2) {

            dateNewFormat += "-" + onlyDate;
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '-0' + onlyDate;
        }

        $('#mydate').val(dateNewFormat);
    });
```

razor view for this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartedDate, new { @id = "mydate", @type = "date", @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution worked out for me. You can show the current date using window.onload function of javascript. See the output.

```js
 var todaydate = new Date();
 var day = todaydate.getDate();
 var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
 var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
 var datestring = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
 window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById("date").value = datestring;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date"/ >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
Date: <input type="text" id="demo"/>
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('demo').value= Date();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use this code. this will helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="frmDateReg" required id="frmDate"  >


<script>
function getDate(){
var todaydate = new Date();
var day = todaydate.getDate();
var month = todaydate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
var datestring = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
document.getElementById("frmDate").value = datestring; //don't need ()
}

document.getElementById("frmDate").onload = getDate(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="text" id="frmDate"></input>
```

JavaScript

```
var date = new Date();
document.getElementById("frmDate").value = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rajbaral/92yko7et/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT>
var currentDate = new Date();
var date1 = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
var mon = currentDate.getDate();
if (mon<10)
    mon="0"+mon
var year = currentDate.getYear();
var hour = currentDate.getHours();
var dn="pm"
if (hour<12)
    dn="am"
if (hour>12)
    hour=hour-12
if (hour==0)
    hour=12
var minute = currentDate.getMinutes();
if (minute < 10){
    minute = "0" + minute
}
var second = currentDate.getSeconds();
if (second < 10){
    second = "0" + second
}
var today = date1+"/"+mon+"/"+year+" Time: "+hour+":"+minute+":"+second+" "+dn
var filePath = "\\\\servername\\maindirectory\\somedirectory\\filenametopostto.xlsx";
function setDate()
{
    f1.tDate.value=today;
}
</script>
```

Result in your text box is:

> 5/28/2019 Time: 3:03:01 pm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the current date on the input field date

```js
var today = new Date();

var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

// today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;
today = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
document.getElementById('dateto1').value = today;
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <label>Date</label>
  <input type="date" name="dateto1" id="dateto1" class="form-control">
</div>
```